# Conditional filter with if statements

Tags: r, if-statement

My data consists of columns and rows. Each column has "NA" and different numbers.
 **For example column1 is:**

`2
 1
 1
 NA
 1
 NA
 NA
 NA`

I want to assign a column id to the numbers in each column.

```
for(j in 1:54){
    if(!(col[j] <-"NA")){
    col[j] <- i
    }
}
```

**Expected result for column1:**

`1
 1
 NA
 NA
 NA
 1
 NA
 NA
 1`

**column 2: **

`2
 2
 NA
 NA
 NA
 2
 NA
 NA
 2`

Comment: You test for `NA` with `is.na()`. `NA` is not the same as `"NA"`.

Comment: But i want to look NOT NA

Comment: OK? `!is.na()` should do then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
v <- c(2, 1, NA, NA, 4, 5, NA)
id <- ifelse(!is.na(v), 1, NA)
id
1  1 NA NA  1 1 NA
```

This means you don't need the for loop here. If you can apply a function to a vector you should avoid using the for loop.

Also, please provide your data so that others can actually use it (like in my code above).

EDIT

According to the comments you have multiple columns. You can use same code. See here

```
df <- data.frame(a= c(2, 1, NA, NA, 4, 5, NA), b= c(3, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, 6))
id <- sapply(1:ncol(df), function(i){
             ifelse(!is.na(df[ , i]), i, NA)})
id
      a  b
[1,]  1  2
[2,]  1 NA
[3,] NA NA
[4,] NA NA
[5,]  1  2
[6,]  1 NA
[7,] NA 2
```

Comment: i have 1259 columns. So i need a loop in here

Comment: How can i save every column after editing.Like: 1 1 NA NA 1 1 NA >2 NA 2 NA NA 2 2

Comment: I do not fully understand the problem. Provide data with dput(head(data)) or so.

Comment: dput(head(MyData))
structure(list(NA. = c(2L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 8L), NA..1 = c(2L, 
NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA), NA..2 = c(2L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA), X1 = c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, 8L), NA..3 = c(2L, NA, 2L, NA, 7L, NA), X1.1 = c(NA, 
NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA), X1.2 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), NA..4 = c(2L,

Comment: for(i in 1:1259) {
 
  col <- MyData[[i]]
  
  for(j in 1:54){
    if(!is.na(col[j])){
      col[j] <- i
      
    }
    
  }
  
} i edited my data with this codes but how can i save column by column

Comment: @Enes I changed my answer. Maybe it answers your question now

Comment: @Enes does my post now answer your question?

Comment: #Read all column until end
    for(i in 1:1259) {
    #assign to col variable 
      col <- MyData[[i]]
    #get each column value  
      for(j in 1:54){
    # if it is not null
            if(!is.na(col[j])){
    #assing with column id
          col[j] <- i
          
        }
      }
    }